# how do i initialize my app using firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

am trying to initailize app in my firebase project but it not working instead am getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apps'), please am i doing wrong here

this is my code
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

```
const app = !firebase.apps.length 
  ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  : firebase.app();
```

Answer (score 0):

firebase.apps is not existing or is probably not defined

Try initializing firebase like this
`const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`

I got that from the official firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

Comment: its working like this but i want to protect my app because am using server side rendering and i don't want it to initialize the app if it already initialized

Answer (score 0):

use `.getApps()` instead of `.apps`

Comment: still showing thesame Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getApps')

Comment: which version are you using? on `"firebase": "^9.6.4"` works correctly

Comment: am using "firebase": "^9.6.7"